# Parse only the text value from inner `a` element with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Im looking to parse just the text of a css selector with beautiful soup.

The css selector is: `td a`. If The output of `td` doesnt have an `a` associated with it, dont parse it.

I have rough code that looks like:

```
req  = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
soup.find("id", {"id": "monatevent"})
```

The html looks like:

```
<td id="monat">5</td>
<td id="monat">6</td>
<td id="monatevent"><a href="file?mdu=82383783">7</a></td>
```

I want to extract only `monatevent` and specially the `7` from its inner `a` element.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that it's contained within an `<a>......</a>` tag, then:

```
soup.find('td', {'id': 'monatevent'}).find('a').text
```

Returns:

```
7
```

Keep in mind that this will return an error if `soup.find('td', {'id': 'montaevent'})` returns `None`, in which case you could handle this with a `try-except` block.

If you would like to find all that meet the criteria and create a list:

```
output = [i.find('a').text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'id': 'monatevent'})]
```

Again, this assumes that all of the tags include an internal `<a>` tag. If not, then do:

```
output = []
tags = soup.find_all('td', {'id': 'monatevent'})
for i in tags:
    try:
        output.append(i.find('a').text)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Does this find multiple iterations of this selector? e.g. `<td id="monatevent"><a href="file?mdu=82383783">7</a></td>` and `<td id="monatevent"><a href="file?mdu=82383783">8</a></td>` for example?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `find` based on tag name

```
soup.find("td", {"id": "monatevent"})
# <td id="monatevent"><a href="file?mdu=82383783">7</a></td>

soup.find("td", {"id": "monatevent"}).text
# '7'
```